# How can I find the $\dim$ of an orthogonal space $S^\perp$ and help with $rank AB$ properties

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a bit confused as to how we would find the dimension of an orthogonal space given a space S. I understand that the dimension of an orthogonal space is the number of vectors in the basis of its column space. Would the dimension of the orthogonal space be the pivot columns of $S^T$?

For example,
$$
S =
\begin {bmatrix}
2 & 6\\
2 & -2\\
2 & -12\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$

Transposing the matrix gives us
$$
S^{\perp} =
\begin {bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 2\\
6 & -2 & -12\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$

Then
$$
RREF(S^{\perp}) =
\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac54\\
0 & 1 & \frac 94\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$

So the # pivot columns are 2. Then does it follow that the dimension of $S^{\perp}$ is 2?

My second question had to do with the properties of $Rank\, AB$. My professor has shown rank proofs where we prove that $Rank AB \le Rank B^T$. I just don't mathematically understand these rank proofs. Can someone explain from a basic level how the properties of $Rank\, AB$ work? What are some basic notions about Rank AB that I can take away?

Comment: Do you mean *the number* of pivot columns?

Answer (score 2):

To find the dimension of the space $S$, we can consider that $\dim S + \dim S^\perp = 3$, which is the dimension of the space in which they are contained. Another way is to set up the system of equations. We know that vectors that are orthogonal to both vectors in the base of $S$ will also be orthogonal to any vector in the space generated by the base. In other words, following your example, we want to solve the system:

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  2\\
  2\\
  2
 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z
 \end{pmatrix} = 0, \quad \begin{pmatrix}
  6\\
  -2\\
  -12
 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z
 \end{pmatrix} = 0.
 \
$$

This can be rewritten as:

$$  
 \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 2 & 2\\
  6 & -2 & -12
 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z
 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  0
 \end{pmatrix}.
 \
$$

This is equivalent to finding the null space of the matrix $S^{T}$ (transpose of S). Using Gaussian elimination:

$$ 
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 2 & 2\\
 6 & -2 & -12
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 2 & 2\\
 0 & -8 & -18
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 \boxed{1} & 1 & 1\\
 0 & \boxed{1} & \frac{9}{4}
\end{array}\right)\longrightarrow\begin{cases}
 x=-z-y=\frac{5}{4}\lambda\\
 y=-\frac{9}{4}\lambda\\
 z=\lambda
\end{cases}N\left(S^{T}\right)=\text{span}\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{5}{4}\\
 -\frac{9}{4}\\
 1
\end{array}\right)\right\}. 
\
$$

So, the null space of $S^{T}$, $N\left(S^{T}\right)$ has a dimension of $1$.

Another way to see this is to consider that the rank plus the dimension of the null space of a matrix is always equal to the number of columns of the matrix. In our case, since $S^{T}$ has rank 2 (its rows are linearly independent), the dimension of the null space is 1, and therefore, $2 + 1 = 3$, which is the number of columns.

For the second question, that $\text{Rank}AB \le \text{Rank}B^{T}$, considering that the dimension of the column space of a matrix is its rank, and also considering that $\text{Rank}A = \text{Rank}A^{T}$.

So, $\text{Rank}AB = \text{Rank}(AB)^{T} = \text{Rank}B^{T}A^{T}$. Let $v \in \text{Col}(B^{T}A^{T})$, which means there exists a column $x$ such that $v = B^{T}A^{T}x = B^{T}\left(A^{T}x\right) = B^{T}x^{\prime}$. Then, $v \in \text{Col}B^{T}$.